# Where is a Websphere Portlet Application 'Title' stored

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm using the Websphere (6.1) Portal Administration page. I expand the 'Portlet Management menu and click on 'Applications'. I see a list of the portlet applications but some of them show "Application Name not available for this Application" in the title column. Where is a portal application 'Application Name' supposed to be stored in order to be shown in this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the id attribute of the portlet-app element within the portlet.xml.  In the example below this would be "com.test.portlets.testportlet.TestPortlet".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" 
    id="com.test.portlets.testportlet.TestPortlet">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>TestPortlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>TestPortlet</display-name>
        <display-name xml:lang="en">TestPortlet</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.test.portlets.testportlet.TestPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>wps.markup</name>
            <value>html</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <resource-bundle>com.test.portlets.testportlet.nl.TestPortletResource</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>TestPortlet</title>
            <short-title>TestPortlet</short-title>
            <keywords>TestPortlet</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Comment: It doesn't specifically document that the id attribute is used as the app name, but the links below mentiones what should be used in the deployment descriptors for portlet apps.  Hope that helps.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_6.1.5/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/dev/wpsptdesc.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_6.1.5/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/j2ee.html